# Building a Folder in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, build

I'm working in Visual Studio 2017.  I wanted to open a folder of files, so I clicked File -----> Open ------> Folder    and selected the folder containing all my files.

When I view the Solution Explorer, I can see all of my programming files.  However, I am unable to build my project and run it.  Is there any way to build and run a folder in Visual Studio?  I've tried selecting the .cpp file that I wanted to build specifically, but there's still no build/debug option.

In fact, under the Debug menu, the F5 Start option is grayed out.  Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a Visual Studio project first, and then add those files to the project. What you are doing right now is just using VS as an editor and viewer.